# View can't find the Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model

```
 class Person {
    public int id {get;set;}
    public String name {get;set;}
}
```

And in the View

```
 @model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Person>
    @foreach (var p in Model){
    @Html.TextBox(p.name)
    }
```

But when i try to run the Application i get

> System.NullReferenceException

on the line

```
`@Html.TextBox(p.name)`
```

The Controller

```
public ActionResult Add(){
return View();
}
```

Any ideas. I am trying to send a List of Person to the View so that i can generate multiple rows for entry.

Comment: please add your action method code as well.

Comment: Add your action method that populates the IEnumerable so we can see whats missing. Obviously the name field is not populated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display a multiple records form, your view should be like this.

```
@model Project.Models.Person

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div id="formData">
        <button type="button" id="Add" onclick="Add();">Add</button>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
<script>
    function Add(){
        document.getElementById("Add").innerHtml += "@Html.EditorFor(m => m.name)";
    }
</script>
```

And then you can implement a post method.

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Add(IEnumerable<Person> list)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not return any list from action method to view. Change your view to

```
@model Project.Models.Person
@Html.TextBox("name")
```

Comment: Still gives the same exception

Comment: you did not return any list from action method to view. check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Add(){
var objPerson = new List<Person>();
objPerson[0].name = ""; // As you want to display blank textboxes for your Form. currently it will show only one textbox.
return View(objPerson);
}
```

Your Action method should be something like this. You are not passing any value of your model in view side. So it is getting P (your model) NULL and not able to find `p.name` so it is giving `Null Exception` error.

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: But i want the view to display a form (a multiple form) so that multiple records can be entered at once. I don't want to display any records.

Comment: It should be List<Person> since the model is expecting an IEnumerable

Comment: If you want to display a form for multiple records than you should use `@HTML.TextboxFor(Model => Model.name)` and put it in for loop. Add a `button` to `ADD more rows`. Your approach should something like that. This way you can't achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The System.NullReferenceException occurs because you didn't send any data to the view from controller. Hence the value of model should be null and it throws an error.

To overcome this, you could pass the data from controller and can be display it in view page.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Add(){

var obj=new List<Person>();

//add your Person data to list and return
return View(obj);
}
```

**View**

```
 @model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Person>
    @foreach (var p in Model){
    @Html.TextBox(p.name)
    }
```